# webpack minify HtmlWebpackPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to minify my html file with Webpack with `HtmlWebpackPlugin` plugin. I manage to make an `index.html` file into my `dist` loader, but I got some trouble to minify it.

```
dist/
node_modules/
src/
   ejs/
   js/
   css/
server.js
webpack.config.js
package.js
```

**webpack.config.js :**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

    entry: './src/js/index.js',

    devtool: 'source-map',

    output: {
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ejs$/,
                use: ['ejs-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [{
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                url: false,
                                minimize: true,
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }]
                })
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/ejs/index.ejs',
            minify: true
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'main_style.css'
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share what trouble you are facing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure what is the issue you are facing exactly, but you can try passing explicit parameters in your minify property instead of a boolean.
For example, to remove whitespace try the following:

Try:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/ejs/index.ejs',
    filename: 'index.ejs',
    minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true
    }
})
```

This works for me.

For the full list of options check the [documentation](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference).

Comment: You right. I have already tested it with multi minify options. That also worker for my. So that mean, I have to put all these options in my ``webpack.config.js`` to completly minify my html file ?

Comment: @Renjus Define what you mean by completely minifying your html. Usually just stripping whitespace will save you a considerable amount of bytes. The other options can depend on the library(if any) you are using for your front-end. If you are using React this is enough, since the rest of the HTML will be added by javascript and I'm guessing you already are minifying your js files.

Comment: Yes my js and css files are already minified. When I said "minify" my html, that mean it look like my js or css files. No space and all the code following each other. If I use ``collapseWhitespace``, my html is smaller but it don't look like my js or css. After, I understand what you said. Maybe I don't need to do more. Using collapseWhitespace is enough.

Comment: Very very thank you! I thought that the minify options are true and false. KANSHA!

Comment: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#minification states that if the value is true, `collapseWhitespace` along with some other options would be applied. But apparently that is not the case. We need to provide the object explicitly.

Comment: it cannot minify the html code surrounded by `<script type=text/ng-template></script>`.

Answer (score 3):

This configuration works for my projects:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          inject: "body",
          hash: true,
          template: './src/ejs/index.ejs',
          filename: 'index.ejs',
          minify: {
            html5                          : true,
            collapseWhitespace             : true,
            minifyCSS                      : true,
            minifyJS                       : true,
            minifyURLs                     : false,
            removeAttributeQuotes          : true,
            removeComments                 : true, // false for Vue SSR to find app placeholder
            removeEmptyAttributes          : true,
            removeOptionalTags             : true,
            removeRedundantAttributes      : true,
            removeScriptTypeAttributes     : true,
            removeStyleLinkTypeAttributese : true,
            useShortDoctype                : true
          },
        }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the `minify: true` option did not work.
Based on the document, it should work. At this time, I added the default options to make the same result.

> If the minify option is set to true (the default when webpack's mode is 'production'), the generated HTML will be minified using html-minifier-terser and the following options:

```
{
  collapseWhitespace: true,
  removeComments: true,
  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
  removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
  useShortDoctype: true
}
```